# Generate html tags with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, tags

I am new to web developing and I was wondering how to generate html tags and change only the content using javascript. For example :

`<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6 portfolio-item">
<img class="img-responsive" src="myFolder/rta.jpg">
</div></div>`

How to create a loop that will automatically generate other tags ,so that i don't need to copy and paste the whole div again and again ?I just need to change the names of the image file and show all the images on the web page.

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

This is what functions are for - to avoid repeating the code. For example:

```
function buildDivs(image) {

  return '<div class="row">' +
         '<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6 portfolio-item">' + 
         '<img class="img-responsive" src="' + image + '">' +
         '</div></div>';
}
```

And then just call the function with:

```
buildDivs('myFolder/rta.jpg');
```

and you'll get the same result string as in your example.

Then, when you need another image, just do:

```
buildDivs('someFolder/anotherImage.jpg');
```

---

*Note that this example works with strings, not nodes.*

Answer (score 0):

First you get the element where you want to put the tags into

```
var div = document.getElementById('Foo');
```

Then you can set the html inside the tag. You can just push a string of the elements you want.

```
div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + "<div class='row'>";
```

then you just itterate through the items that you want to add

```
for (srcItem in list){
    div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + "<div class='row'>" +
    "<div class='col-md-3 col-xs-6 portfolio-item'>" +
    <img class='img-responsive' src='" + srcItem + "'>" +
    "</div></div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

The quick and dirty answer to this is that you can store your image sources in an array and loop over them, adding the source string to predefined markup, like this:

```
var srcs = ['https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/03/Popemobile_passes_the_White_House.jpg/300px-Popemobile_passes_the_White_House.jpg',
          'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d1/Popemobil_Mai_2007.jpg/220px-Popemobil_Mai_2007.jpg',
          'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/17/Seat_Panda_1980-1985_Papamobil_Madrid_1982_frontright_2008-03-28_A.jpg/220px-Seat_Panda_1980-1985_Papamobil_Madrid_1982_frontright_2008-03-28_A.jpg'];


 for(var i = 0; i < srcs.length; i++){
    $('body').append('<img src="' + srcs[i] + '"/>');
 }
```

Demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/ojk0s966/

However, if you're planning on doing a lot of this it can get pretty unwieldy. In which case, you're better off using something that was made for templating, like http://handlebarsjs.com/.